# ScheduledTaskAgent not working for updating tiles in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1

I am working on a Windows Phone 7 app and trying to implement the features of a Windows Phone 8 like wide tiles into it. I achieved it using reflection but when i wanted to update the tile using a ScheduledAgent for a Periodic Task the tile is not getting created.

The scheduled agent OnInvoke code looks like

```
protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
{
    //TODO: Add code to perform your task in background
     if (task is PeriodicTask)
     {
         //Update the tile using Scheduled Task
         CreateTileForWindowsPhone.CreateWideTile();
     }
     NotifyComplete();
}
```

I created the tile using this code

```
public class CreateTileForWindowsPhone
{
    private static Version TargetedVersion = new Version(7, 10, 8858);
    public static bool IsTargetedVersion { get { return Environment.OSVersion.Version >= TargetedVersion; } }

    public static void CreateWideTile()
    {
        if (IsTargetedVersion)
        {
            try
            {
                // Get the new FlipTileData type.
                Type flipTileDataType = Type.GetType("Microsoft.Phone.Shell.FlipTileData, Microsoft.Phone");
                // Get the ShellTile type so we can call the new version of "Update" that takes the new Tile templates.

                Type shellTileType = Type.GetType("Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ShellTile, Microsoft.Phone");
                // Loop through any existing Tiles that are pinned to Start.

                QuotesCollection aq = new QuotesCollection();
                Random rand = new Random();
                int randNum = rand.Next(0, 163);

                //String wideBackStr = "Dont be the same, Be Better.";
                String wideBackStr = aq.quotes[randNum];

                foreach (var tileToUpdate in ShellTile.ActiveTiles)
                {
                    // Get the constructor for the new FlipTileData class and assign it to our variable to hold the Tile properties.
                    var UpdateTileData = flipTileDataType.GetConstructor(new Type[] { }).Invoke(null);

                    // Set the properties. 
                    SetProperty(UpdateTileData, "WideBackgroundImage", new Uri("/images/QuottedWideTile.png", UriKind.Relative));
                    SetProperty(UpdateTileData, "WideBackContent", wideBackStr);
                    // Invoke the new version of ShellTile.Update.
                    shellTileType.GetMethod("Update").Invoke(tileToUpdate, new Object[] { UpdateTileData });
                    break;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Tile Error Caught");
            }
        }
    }

    private static void SetProperty(object instance, string name, object value)
    {
        var setMethod = instance.GetType().GetProperty(name).GetSetMethod();
        setMethod.Invoke(instance, new object[] { value });
    }
}
```

i made a register agent method to register the Periodic Task

```
    private void RegisterAgent()
    {
        string taskName = "MyTask";
        try
        {

            if (ScheduledActionService.Find(taskName) != null)
            {
                //if the agent exists, remove and then add it to ensure
                //the agent's schedule is updated to avoid expiration
                ScheduledActionService.Remove(taskName);
            }

            PeriodicTask periodicTask = new PeriodicTask(taskName);
            periodicTask.Description = "Random Quote Update On Tile";
            ScheduledActionService.Add(periodicTask);

        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
        }
        catch (SchedulerServiceException schedulerException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(schedulerException.Message);
        }
    }
```

and called the register in the app launching

```
    private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterAgent();
    }
```

But the wide tile is not being created when i run the app.
Wide tile creation used to work before i used scheduled agents to update the tile. I used to create a wide tile just by calling that function in application launching.

```
    private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
    {
        CreateTileForWindowsPhone.CreateWideTile();
    }
```

WHy is the tile not being created. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Why target WP7 and do this with reflection? Have you tried upgrading to WP8 and updating your tile?

Comment: Currently im working on Wp7 on vs2010. So I use reflection to create tiles.
I just caught a "invalid cross-thread error". Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like you should be running some code on the UI thread. Use Dispatcher RunAsync

Comment: What's the status of this?

Comment: @Mikko Thanks for the suggestion. But i figured it out. It works. There were some apis that were included in the Class CreateTileForWindowsPhone that weren't supposed to be used since they are not supported by ScheduledAgents. So hence the wide tiles were not being created. Removed them and my code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
    CreateTileForWindowsPhone.CreateWideTile);
```